# jQuery Plugin development Events Handlers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn to develop jQuery plugins. I readed the base tutorial on jQuery site, and try to understand how it works and how structure the plugin.

I did some fast test, but i'm stuck now and i don't know how to get past.

Here is the code:

```
var myElement = $("#Foo");
var myButton = $("#Bar");
(function($) {
var showAlert;
var mathWorks;
var methods = {
    init : function(options) {

    // Declaring Default Options
    var defaults = 
    {
        option1 : 'Default',
        option2 : false
    }

    // Merge Options
        var opt =  $.extend(defaults, options);

    showAlert = function(txt)
    {
        alert(txt);
    }

    mathWorks = function(a,b)
    {
        alert('Result of '+a+'*'+b+' = '+ a*b);
    }


    methods.doSomething(opt.option1);
},

doSomething: function(text)
{
    alert(text);
},

doMathWorks: function(a,b)
{

    mathWorks(a,b)
}

};

$.fn.testPlugin = function() {
    var method = arguments[0];

    if(methods[method]) {
        method = methods[method];
        arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    } else if( typeof(method) == 'object' || !method ) {
        method = methods.init;
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.pluginName' );
        return this;
    }
    return method.apply(this, arguments);   

}
})(jQuery);
```

**Where do i declare Events Handlers?**

Like:

```
myButton.bind('click', function()
        {
            alert('test');
            //methods.doSomething("Testing");
});
```

And also, It is correct to declare elements variables before the plugin, as i did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fully define your private utility functions `showAlert` and `mathWorks` outside the `init()` method. Declaring them outside and defining inside offers no advantage and is potentially confusing.

Event handlers can be attached inside any method to which you pass a jQuery collection (or a utility function called by such a method). Inside the method be sure to have a `return this.each(function(){...})` structure, thereby addressing all members of the collection, and returning it for method chaining.

Comment: But, if i define function outside the init method, i cannot use setting, because they are defined inside. And if i declare and define functions inside the method(s), i cannot use them in other methods. I'm a bit confused..

Comment: To get settings right, you need to understand two things. (1) Settings are specific to the DOM elements of the jQuery collection on which the plugin is invoked. (2) The plugin itself retains no record of previous calls to any of its methods. To allow `init()` to communicate its settings to other methods, they are typically set, in whole or in part, to `.data()` properties of the DOM elements in the original jQuery collection (which was passed to `init()`). The [jQuery Plugins/Authoring tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the single scope for your plugin, to isolate it from other's plugin and javaScript code on the page.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff608209.aspx) is the great tutorial how to develop your plugins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare event handlers in the `init` method, but use `.on` instead of `.bind`.  I'm assuming these are events that you want to bind to the button as part of plugin behavior.
2. It is not correct to declare elements like you did because your plugin should have no dependency on the existing DOM at all.